# Entity Framework Set PreserveChanges to be default MergeOption

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, fetching-strategy

In a ASP.net mvc 2 project is there a way to set the default MergeOption to PreserveChanges for all entity types?

Currently i have a massive sub that sets all entity types mergeOption.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also need to know how to do this.  However from my research I agree with Garry English.

To avoid a large routine and have a maintenance free method of setting every entity sets MergeOption have a look at this: [Way to automate setting of MergeOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698142/way-to-automate-setting-of-mergeoptions)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, this cannot be set at design time and can only be set at runtime.  Here is a post that shows different ways to set MergeOption:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2010/02/16/setting-entity-framework-mergeoptions-what-works-what-doesn-t.aspx